# window.open() not opening to the specified size on smaller screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to code a popup window that displays the order information based on url parameters. As part of this, the popup is required to load in a new window (not tab) but I'm having problems with this only when viewing on mobile. Desktop works fine, i specify the new window height and width however on mobile it just pops up a desktop size window contents and not resized for mobile

Ive tried adding a JS function to get the screen width and height and use that in the window.open parameters however this has not worked

```
function openNewPopup(url) {
var clientWidth = window.innerWidth;
var clientHeight = window.innerHeight;

if ((clientWidth < 700) {
    var size = "width=" + clientWidth + "," + "height=" + clientHeight;
    orderWindow = window.open(url, "newWindow", size );        
}
    else {
        orderWindow = window.open(url, "newWindow", "width=700, height=750"); //assigns popup window to variable
    }
}
```

The expected output should be a new window with the correct viewport sizing for usability on mobile

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think most mobile browsers always take up the whole screen, so I don't think this is possible

Comment: Sorry that's my bad wording. when opening the new window on mobile, it paints the screen as if the user has enabled "view desktop site" with the contents all zoomed out rather than opening the new window within the correct viewport

Comment: Never mind, solved my issue. Somewhere along the lines I've accidentally deleted the viewport meta from <head>